# symfony 5 custom authentication for API REST

Tags: rest, symfony, fosrestbundle, symfony5

I'm working on a project with Symfony 5.
I created the User entity, created the authentication flow on security.yaml and all works well: if user wants to access to protected area, login page was shown and authentication process works! So good!

Now, I want to build an API REST with FOSRest Bundle.
I've created a specific controller for expose some routes:

```
/**
 * @Rest\Route("/api")
 *
 */

class APICustomController extends AbstractController
{
    ...
    /**
    * @Rest\Get("/shoes")
    * @param Request $request
    * @Method({"GET"})
    *
    * @return JsonResponse
    */
    public function getShoes(Request $request){

        ....
        return JsonResponse::fromJsonString(array('msg' => 'OK'));

    }

}
```

Here my security.yaml

```
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_VIEWER: ROLE_USER

    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username
        api_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: api_token
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\DealmapLoginAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout

        api:
            stateless: true
            lazy: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\TokenAuthenticator
            pattern: ^/api/
            provider: api_user_provider

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

I followed the steps given here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html

The problem is the call below

```
curl -X GET \
  http://www.example.com/api/shoes \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'x-auth-token: test'
```

it is protected by the **main** firewall (so it returns me the login page), and not by **api** as expected. I expect to receive an error message in json format.

What's wrong??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I found the solution!

I'm posting it here in case someone might need it in the future.

The configuration was all correct, but the reason why the path */api/shoes* was managed by the main firewall was due to the order of execution of the rules.

The firewall **main** handles all the rules, while the **api** one handles only the ones with the *^/api* pattern, so the most stringent rules should go first in the firewall definition in the security.yaml, as below:

```
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_VIEWER: ROLE_USER

    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username
        api_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: api_token
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        api:
            stateless: true
            lazy: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\TokenAuthenticator
            pattern: ^/api/
            provider: api_user_provider
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\DealmapLoginAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```